# ssh proxycommand with same password

Tags: ssh, bash, windows-10

I have a jump/proxy host ("jump") I use to access my final destination host ("final").  I have it configured correctly to allow me in.  However, it requires I enter my passphrase twice (once for "jump", once for "final".)

~/.ssh/config...

```
Host jump
        Hostname jump.domain.com
        User username
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host final
        Hostname final.otherdomain.com
        User username
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ProxyCommand ssh -q jump -W %h:%p
```

Is there a secure way of allowing the password from the first entry to be passed to the second?  In addition to just the inconvenience, I worry about locking myself out with entering a complex password several times each time I need to access "final".

I do not have admin rights to either "jump" or "final", but could request reasonable changes from our support tech.

I don't imagine this matters, but this is in Bash via WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

**PS:** I've found a couple threads on the StackExchange network and Google that involves **in**secure means via scripting.  I am hoping it is just something I can add to my config to enable it.

I also found [this post](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) from github that appears to cover a (perhaps) similar effect as to what I am trying to achieve...

"This is sort of like asking a friend to enter their password so that you can use their computer."

Using the [tips](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/#your-system-must-allow-ssh-agent-forwarding) there, I checked the ForwardAgent setting for both "jump" and "final" and both have it disabled...

```
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep Forward

ForwardAgent no
```

Is this in fact referring to what I am trying to achieve?  Are there security implications driving this being shut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with passwords.

If you use public key authentication instead, and load the private key(s) into a running ssh-agent on the client, then the logins to both the jump and final hosts will use the key and log you in. You'll only have to enter a password once, when you load the private key into the ssh-agent.

Comment: You will have to enable Agent Forwarding on the jump host, IIRC.